# IDEA, how to disassociate editor with file type?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a new resource file in my directory named `protected.keys`. When creating it, i asked `IntelliJ` to treat it as `properties`.

[image]

Instead i'd like to change this to `text` how can i do this please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change it in `File` | `Settings` | **File Types**, remove the file name or extension from the `Properties files` and assign it to the `Text files`.